# Django: How does model class take constructor arguments when no __init__() is defined?

Tags: python, django

In my app polls, we have the file models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And after starting a shell with `python manage.py shell`, we can write this:

```
from polls.models import Question
q = Question(question_text = "What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```

The `Question` class is clearly taking constructor arguments when an object is created. But in our class definition of `Question` in `models.py`, there is no specification of any constructor arguments. So how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Question` class **inherits** `models.Model` class, it gets the constructor from there itself.